# Python legend marker location changes when using alternative font

Tags: python, matplotlib

To comply with journal typography, I would like to use Bitstream-Charter within my figures. Until now, this has worked flawlessly, but I have discovered a small problem when using subscripts and superscripts.

The following produces a legend as expected, with the markers (lines) centered vertically with the labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y = x**2

plt.figure(dpi=200)
plt.plot(x, y,
         label='$T^*_s$')
plt.plot(x, y,
         label='$T^*_g$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

While the following produces a legend where the markers are shifted downward (aligned with the bottom of the T).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y = x**2

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text', **{'latex.preamble':
                  '\\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}'})

plt.figure(dpi=200)
plt.plot(x, y,
         label='$T^*_s$')
plt.plot(x, y,
         label='$T^*_g$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there anyway to shift these markers upwards, ti align with the middle of the T? I've tried using some `\vspace` commands, but they don't work.

Comment: I had this same problem, if you save the image (e.g. ```savefig('img.pdf')``` ), then the text and marker will be aligned in the saved img. It is a problem with the backend  display somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the slickest or most pythonic of solutions, I'll admit, but one relatively simple idea would be to make the legend slightly transparent and then put the legend labels in by hand.  This means that you have to go into more detail when setting up the legend (i.e. specifying the lines, colors, location, etc.) but it allows for more flexibility.  Also, rendering the image may move the text somewhat, making it different from what you may see in your window, so you might need to play with locations a bit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y = x**2

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text', **{'latex.preamble':
              '\\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}'})

plt.figure(dpi=200)
plt.plot(x, y, c='green')
line1 = Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='_', color="blue")
line2 = Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='_',color="green")
leg = plt.legend((line1,line2),('',''),numpoints=1, loc=1)
leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.2)
plt.text(0.955, 0.925, "$T^*_s$")
plt.text(0.955, 0.865, "$T^*_g$")
plt.show()
```

[image]